# Want to print the data in new line

Tags: swift

**Edit 1** - I am getting the data from TextField and i have to display it in TextView. I cant post my code here, Hence this example

The below code give the output as **abhisudeeptest**
where i want the output as required output

```
var x = "abhi"
var y = "sudeep"
var z = "test"
var a = ""
var arr = [String]()
arr.append(x)
arr.append(y)
arr.append(z)
for i in arr {
    a = a + i
}
print(a)
```

output -

```
abhisudeeptest
```

required output

```
abhi
sudeep
test
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `joined(separator: )`

```
let a = ["abhi", "sudeep", "test"].joined(separator: "\n")

print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a newline:

```
a = a + i + "\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new line character:

```
var x = "abhi"
var y = "sudeep"
var z = "test"
var a = ""
var arr = [String]()
arr.append("\(x) \n")
arr.append("\(y) \n")
arr.append("\(z) \n")
for i in arr {
    a = a + i
}
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
 let x = "abhi"
    let y = "sudeep"
    let z = "test"
    var a = ""
    var b = ""
    var arr = [String]()
    arr.append(x)
    arr.append(y)
    arr.append(z)
    for i in 0..<arr.count
    {
        if  i == 0
        {
            a = a +  arr[i]
        }
        else
        {
            a = a + "\n" + arr[i]
        }
    }
    print (a)
```

or

```
 b = arr.joined(separator: "\n")
    print(b)
```